# Laravel included template is not parsing / running foreach loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have included a couple of files.

my home.blade.php has the following:

```
@include('includes.header')
```

my header.blade.php in includes folder has the following

```
@include('elements.pendingTasksLi', array('tasks'=>$tasks))
```

and my elements/pendingTasksLi.php file has the following

```
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
<li>
        <a class="todo-actions" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                <span class="desc" style="opacity: 1; text-decoration: none;">{{{$task\['title'\]}}}</span>
                <span class="label label-danger" style="opacity: 1;"> {{{$task\['deadLineTime'\]}}}</span>
        </a>
</li>
@endforeach
```

This code in the pendingTakstsLi file is never executed as a loop but only as a simple text.

This is what the output looks like...

```
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
{{{$task['title']}}} {{{$task['deadLineTime']}}}
@endforeach
```

I am not sure what to do... Please advise...

Check a screen here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8emZk.png

Thanks

Jyot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that your "pendingTasksLi" view ends in ".php" and not ".blade.php" which would prevent it from being parsed as a blade view.

Comment: Oh Boy! You are right! Silly of me to not see that!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and as mentioned above you forgot the .blade before the .php

If you want to use expressions like this: {{ $variable}} and want them to be parsed you always have to add .blade in the name pefore the .php extension of the file.